# Add another row when click to add new question button

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, npm, material-ui

ReactJS >

I want to show by default 10 rows And a button with "Add a new question" so that would be the 11th row.

[current row image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUGhF.png)

Currently it's only one row [refer to the image below]. And I want 10 initial rows and then add as required. And as many rows can add it could be able to scroll. And on submit I would have all the filled data from that input component. Maybe just console.log when to submit or to alert for now.
NOTE- using formik (could also use state)

Not adding code, because it's a large component. perhaps here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-moon-srlub), When I am looking for a solution. If anyone can help me would be great. Please got stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the use case in your case. But here is the simple way to do that.

```
export default function App() {
const [elements, setElements ] = useState([<QuestionColumn />]);

const element = () => (
  <QuestionColumn />
)
console.log(elements)
return (
<div className="App">
{elements.map((child) => child)}
  <button
        onClick={() => {
            setElements([
                ...elements,
                element()
            ])
        }}
    >
        Add New Question
    </button>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Yadab, For example I added 5 rows, Okay. Now I want submit button and when I hit submit button it should display alert and all filled data as per row in 5 different objects (because 5 rows were filled) it should display object wise on submit.